# How to allow only specific users to specific pages when using query parameters like ...?id=3

Tags: asp.net, membership

I have a page that shows some data depending on the id param in request.

The user must be logged in

How should I stop the user from accessing certain ids that belong to other users. Is redirect the best choice?

Comment: Can't you create `user-roles` and mange from that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on the server-side before rendering the page, then redirect...etc:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string bla = Request["key"] != null ? Request["key"] : "";
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(bla))
    if (bla=="yourvaluetocheck" && !User.IsInRole("theroletouse"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/permissiondenied.aspx");
    }
}
```

This a very simple example, I would put this type of logic in a central place in my application for re-use.